# Data handeling with c# chart control

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a quick question for you all. This is my first time dealing with serial I/O, and was wondering what the most efficient method is. Ill be reading in from a laser through rs-232.

From what I can tell from researching it I can accomplish this by using a background worker to create a buffer from the serial port, then have the main thread access that buffer to plot and analyze the points. Is there a more efficient / reliable way to do this ,or is this approach going to be my best bet?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you read from the device depends on how data is retrieved from it. I have an application that gets data from a strain gauge (attached to a meter). This meter autonomously spits out readings, so I don't have to poll it. Because of this I simply use the `SerialPort`s DataReceived event and add data to an array.

I use the Microsoft Chart Control (built into .NET 4.0) which lives on the UI thread, so it has to be updated from the UI thread. The data comes in pretty fast (~100 points per second), so what I do is build a 100 point array and BeginInvoke (Winforms) that array off to the UI thread while starting a new array. This way the UI is updated periodically (~1 update per second).

If, on the other hand, your device requires polling (you have to ask it for data each time), then you'll want a dedicated thread that sits in a tight loop polling.

Comment: Thanks! I believe the laser i am using will spit out readings as well, so I'll head down that path.